# Powershell remoting - creating objects remotely

Tags: powershell, remoting

I am trying to create object and operate on it using remoting as below:

```
$foldername = "C:\test"
$computername ="remotecomputer"

Invoke-Command -computername $computername -Scriptblock {$newquotaobj = New-Object -ComObject Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManager}
Invoke-Command -computername $computername -Scriptblock {$newquotasrc = $newquotaobj).GetQuota($Using:foldername)}
```

My understanding that `$newquotaobj` would be deserialized and sent back - but it does not seem to happen. Is it even possible to achive my goal here - i.e creating com object remotely and operating on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invoke-Command` returns the output, not the objects created. If you want to remotely operate COM objects via `Invoke-Command` you have to include the code in the script block:

```
$foldername = "C:\test"
$computername ="remotecomputer"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock {
  $newquotaobj = New-Object -ComObject Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManager
  $newquotasrc = $newquotaobj.GetQuota($args[0])
  $newquotasrc   # <-- this will be returned to the local host
} -ArgumentList $foldername
```

Comment: Thank you very much! All works now , I can create quotas remotely :) Invoke-Command -session $s -Scriptblock { 
                $fsrmremote = New-Object -ComObject Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManager 
                                             
                $qcreate = $fsrmremote.CreateQuota($Using:foldername)
                $qcreate.Description = $Using:qdescription
                $qcreate.QuotaLimit = $Using:qlimitBytes
                $qcreate.Commit()
            }